# \selectcolormodel{gray} not applied to \draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

Today I found something weird. When I use `\selectcolormodel{}` in a `TikZ` drawing the model is only applied to `\fill` and not to `\draw[fill=]`. Does anyone know why?

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[gray]{xcolor} % all draws or fills become gray
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw [fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \fill [cyan] (2,0) rectangle (3,1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\selectcolormodel{gray}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw [fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle (1,1); % expected this one to change
    \fill [cyan] (2,0) rectangle (3,1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And the result is the one below.

[image: Result]

Comment: I don't think it is filling versus drawing. `\draw [cyan] ...` gives you grayscale output, too. And `\fill [fill=cyan]...` does not. TikZ does some complicated things with colour, some of which are designed to work even if `xcolor` is not available and I suspect something there is responsible but the code is well beyond my understanding :(.

Comment: Put the color selection command inside the tikzpicture. TikZ does some initialization and persists throughout the document. Or use `every picture` keys

Comment: Looking at this, I think it's got to be a bug in TikZ (there's no reason to 'expect' this behaviour): have you reported it?

Comment: No I did not. Where can I do it?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/

Comment: Can anyone report this bug? I do not have account in sourceforge.net.

Comment: Bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/349/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following workaround redefines the color in the current target color model via `\colorlet[named]{<color>}{<color>}`. A `\colorlet` without `[named]` does not redefine the color in the target color model, which seems also the problem with the TikZ, which uses `\colorlet` in `\pgfsetfillcolor`. As "unknown" option, TikZ uses `\color` instead, which converts the color on usage (depending on switch `\ifconvertcolorU`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw [fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \fill [cyan] (2,0) rectangle (3,1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\selectcolormodel{gray}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % \colorlet{cyan}{cyan} alone does not convert the color space
    \colorlet[named]{cyan}{cyan}%

    \draw [fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \fill [cyan] (2,0) rectangle (3,1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Did you have an idea why `\usepackage[gray]{xcolor}` is working well and why it is not equivalent to `\selectcolormodel{gray}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile this bug has been fixed (or worked around) in the commit [83b22a](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/83b22a46aa372ccc48e27474da56cb8f0207039e/) available from the development repository of pgf/tikz https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/

[image]