# pgfplot with gray colormodel turns out purple

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \selectcolormodel{gray}
    \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      xtick=data,
      symbolic x coords={A},
    ]
      \addplot coordinates {(A,   1.000)};
      \addplot coordinates {(A,   1.150)};
      \addplot coordinates {(A,   1.393)};
      \addplot coordinates {(A,   1.234)};
      \addplot coordinates {(A,   1.599)}; % this will be purple
      \addplot coordinates {(A,   0.912)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which generates the following bar chart:

[image: purple bar]

I would very much expect the last bar to also be grayscale.
Subsequent bars are still grayscale.

Am I going crazy or doing something wrong?

I know that I can still just add `[style={fill=black!40white}]` to `\addplot` to manually overwrite the color, but why doesn't it do it automatically?

Comment: See e.g. [`\selectcolormodel{gray}` doesn't always work with tikzducks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/385158/82917). Might be a duplicate.

Comment: Indeed using `\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}` before `\usepackage{pgfplots}`, as suggest in the link, switches the purple to a dark gray. Thanks!