# Inconsistent behaviour with tikz and xcolor monochome option

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

When `xcolor` is loaded with the `monochrome` option, colour is disable for only some, but not all `tikz` operations.

- Why is this?
- Is it possible to disable colour for all operations?
- is it possible *not* to disable colour for any operations?

## MWE

(Without the `monochrome` option, everything is drawn in red.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[monochrome]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{Red}% black

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1pt]
  \node (a) [text=red] {Red};% red
  \node (b) [fill=red,below=of a] {};% red
  \node (c) [draw=red,below=of b] {};% red
  \node (d) [above=of a] {\textcolor{red}{Red}};% black
  \draw [red] circle (1);% black
  \path [draw=red] circle (1.2);% red
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385169/2388