# "every path" style affects \node "path" when decorating

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[decorate, decoration=random steps] (0,0) -- (10,0);
  \node[decorate, decoration=random steps, draw, fill=yellow, inner sep=0.5cm] at (5,-2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For a more complex picture, I wanted to apply the same decoration to all lines and nodes, and so I used "every path":

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={decorate, decoration=random steps}]
  \draw (0,0) -- (10,0);
  \node[draw, fill=yellow, inner sep=0.5cm] at (5,-2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, this results in an error: "I cannot decorate an empty path".  I think I understand what the problem is: `\node ...` is replaced with `\path node ...` and we thus have an empty path.

But how can I achieve what I want, namely applying the same decoration to all lines AND nodes (let's assume there a lots of them) without having to specify it explicitly for each `\draw` and `\node` command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem has been solved some time ago by Jake, I think, in this [stellar answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60757/121799). It is sort of the opposite of what you suggest: if you use `\path (<coordinates>) node...`, it works.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={decorate,decoration=random steps}]
  \draw (0,0) -- (10,0);
  \path (5,-2) node[decorate,draw, fill=yellow, inner sep=0.5cm]  {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: The picture looks a bit as if the left edge of the node was straight. However, that's just an accident, as can be seen from the following animation in which the random seed varies.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {1,...,50}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={decorate,decoration=random steps}]
  \pgfmathsetseed{\X}   
  \draw (0,0) -- (10,0);
  \path (5,-2) node[decorate,draw, fill=yellow, inner sep=0.5cm]  {};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: And if you don't want to write `draw,decorate` over and over, you could just append this to the node styles.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={decorate,decoration=random steps},
every node/.append style={draw,decorate}]
  \draw (0,0) -- (10,0);
  \path (5,-2) node[fill=yellow, inner sep=0.5cm]  {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Who would have thought?  But shouldn't this then be considered kind of a bug in TikZ?  In both cases there is an empty path, but only in case do we get an error message...

BTW, I looked at Jake's answer and found it very interesting, but I couldn't find any reference to this problem here.

Comment: @Frunobulax Jake didn't mention the problem but the way he wrote his code suggests that he encountered and just solved it. I prefer to give credit to somebody in case of doubt, and I would hesitate to call it a bug. Ti*k*Z is IMHO a really amazing tool that allows us to do many wonderful things, and in this case it just requires you to slightly change the syntax. Similar things happen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/385158/121799). That is, sometimes commands that appear to be equivalent are not.

Answer (score 6):

apparently `every path` doesn't work as you expected. you still need to explicit say, which lines, shapes has decorate path:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={decoration=random steps}]
  \draw[decorate] (0,0) -- (10,0);
  \node[decorate, draw, fill=yellow, inner sep=0.5cm] at (5,-2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

so, it maybe more handy (for shorter writing) to define path style for example as

```
DP/.style={%decorated path
           decorate, decoration=random steps}
```

and than use as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[DP/.style={%decorated path
                                decorate, decoration=random steps}]
  \draw[DP] (0,0) -- (10,0);
  \node[DP, draw, fill=yellow, inner sep=0.5cm] at (5,-2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]