# TikZ - Repeated text along path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to have some text repeated along a path. I tried what was prescribed in the PGF manual under `/pgf/decoration/text effects/repeat text`, but, as you can see, it doesn't have the effect I want:

[image: Undesired effect]

I'd like something like below, but repeated around the path:

[image: Somewhat desired effect]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [block/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum size=5cm, align=center}]

    \node [block,
           postaction={decoration={text effects along path, text={BOX BOUNDARY\ },
               text effects/.cd,
                   repeat text,
                   character count=\m, character total=\n,
                   characters={text along path, scale=0.5+\m/\n/2}},
               decorate}]
           (box){};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, it does not work with a node. Can you use a `rectangle`? (you can always add your node without text on top of the rectangle)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[%
postaction={decoration={text effects along path, text={BOX BOUNDARY\ },
text effects/.cd,
repeat text,
character count=\m, character total=\n,
characters={text along path, scale=0.5+\m/\n/2}},
decorate},
] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);           
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rectangle with repeated text]

Comment: I'm curious to see if it works on a node with the keys `rotate=5,rotate=-5` set on that node.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: It does not work. I also tried `\path (<coordinates>) node...` instead of `\node` as mentioned here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445918/8650 ,..., combinations of pre/post-actions and direct decoration, and more - I could not make it work.

Comment: It seems to be something to do with how a node path is used - I suspect some interaction between the TikZ and PGF parts that is different to a normal path.  I'm intrigued.

Answer (score 3):

There's definitely something odd happening with decorations and node paths.  I don't know the whys and wherefores, but here's a method that works by repeating the node path out of the context of the node.  This uses my `spath3` library to avoid having to specify the path twice (which, incidentally, shows that it is nothing to do with the *path* and must therefore be to do with how the path around the node is used).

Note that I currently need to use the `overlay` option on the decoration path.  This is because a rectangular node constructs a particular type of path that *no other TikZ construction uses* so I didn't account for it when coding `spath3`.  I'm currently working on fixing that, but in the meantime the bounding box calculation is off.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
% \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/615779/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,spath3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [block/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum size=5cm, align=center}]

    \node [block,
      spath/save=node path,
    ]
    (box){};

    \path[
      overlay, % Needed temporarily
      spath/use=node path,
      decoration={
        text effects along path,
        text={BOX BOUNDARY\ },
        text effects/.cd,
        repeat text,
        character count=\m, character total=\n,
        characters={text along path, scale=0.5+\m/\n/2}
      },
      decorate,
    ];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Decorated node path]