# Grayscale in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was trying to implement an example from the following answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25708/96546 and encountered some strange behaviour. Here is an example:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[radius=0.5cm]
        \selectcolormodel{gray}
        \fill [red] (0,0) circle;
        \fill [green] (1,0) circle;
        \fill [blue] (2,0) circle;

        \draw [->,-latex,thick] (-0.5,-1) -- (1,-1) node[midway,fill=red,scale=0.8]{$hello$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[.]{.}
\label{Fig::Parratt3}
\end{figure}
```

While the colors in the `\fill` commands are all translated to grayscale as required the label of the `\draw` command remains colored. How can I get this in grayscale too?

Background: I'd like to check if the grayscale version of my picture is still legible, i.e. if the colors can be distinguished.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385169/36296

Comment: @samcarter thanks! your linked didn't help directly since it only showed the problems rather than providing a solution. But following the links from there I found: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326367/96546
This did answer my question, which I will mark as a duplicate.

Comment: @ Wolpertinger Another hack I use when I cannot avoid the usage of `fill=...` is to mix the colour with 0% of another colour, e.g. `fill=red!0!white`.